# back-to-top button not appearing

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

Using Javascript, I've added a back-to-top button to my website.  When I scroll, it appears (so the first function below works fine).  However, when I add the second function, the button doesn't even appear when I scroll.  I've been at this for hours!  Have I missed something obvious?

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", appear);

function appear(){
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
    {document.getElementById("button").style = "display: block;"}
  else
    {document.getElementById("button").style = "display: none;"}
};


document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", top);

function top(){
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
};
```

---

**Edit:**

**html**

```html
<img id="button" src="button.jpg" alt="the back-to-top button">
```

**css**

```css
#button {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the issue here, I believe is that `top` is already a property on `window` and you are replacing it by creating a global function called `top`.

This will work if you change your function to something like `goToTop`.

If you log `console.log(window.top)` you'll find something already exists there.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", appear);

function appear(){
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
    {document.getElementById("button").style = "display: block;"}
  else
    {document.getElementById("button").style = "display: none;"}
};

function goToTop(){
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", goToTop);
```

Comment: No worries, happy to help. As you write more and more javascript, this will become something that you won't have to worry about, because all your local functions will be namespaced by the time you get to writing large production-ready js

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`document.getElementById("button").style = "display: block;"`

I think you should write

`document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block"`

similar to the next one.
I refer to this website - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp

Comment: I am still learning javascript and I write it in a way I best understand.  The problem is not in that line of code

Comment: Seems like `top` is a window property, you can do `console.log(top)` to see what's in it. The solution is to rename your function `top()` to other name like `toTop()` and it should work.